# Why does LetsEncrypt consume so much bandwidth

Tags: networking, home-networking, bandwidth

I was looking at my traffic patterns for my home network. Below is a screenshot my bandwidth for various destinations in the past 30mins as seen on my EdgeOS dashboard.

Why is Lets Encrypt's ingress/download traffic so much higher than other sites, like youtube.com for example?

[image: Traffic Analysis]

Comment: It seems like this is either an over-generalization (with EdgeOS counting any site that uses a Lets Encrypt certificate as "Lets Encrypt") or it's just mislabeling some traffic as Let's Encrypt. Ubiquiti is not exactly known for 100% accurate software :) Here's a reddit thread that is relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubiquiti/comments/afbxko/can_anyone_help_me_make_sense_of_what_dpi_is/